# how to keep desktop icon after uninstall application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I am developing win form application in VS2010 C#.
I have created Setup using visual studio installer, when I install shortcuts created on desktop.
I just want to keep desktop shortcut icon as it is after uninstalling application.

So, how can I prevent to deleting desktop shortcuts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A desktop icon is pointing to the location of the application. After uninstalling the application the icon wouldn't make sense anymore.

Comment: I hate desktop icons being made in the first place, Id hate even more if it left icons after uninstall..

Comment: Actually I do setup multiple projects at one location and I took one common shortcut for all projects i.e. there is one console exe file which execute and search into directory of other projects EXE and executed them one by one(i.e. process.start(exefilepath)) ;

Comment: @diiN_ can we prevent to delete desktop shortcut

Comment: The idea of an uninstaller is that it removes all traces of an application from your system, being able to bypass that and leave junk around is a violation of the entire principle of installers,

Comment: after reading your comment you seem to want to use the launcher as a shared component, in which case this may help you, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2009/12/21/about-shared-components/ as a shared component is only removed when the last item using it is removed